# Tweepy retweet bot keeps looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

So I have been working on a twitter bot for a while now, and I am running into a problem with it. Every time I include the `api.retweet()` function it runs my function twice. To stop it all I have to do is comment it out. Every time it runs twice it causes an error and kills my program.

I fixed that part with a try except setup, but still it replies twice, and tries to like it twice. I don't understand why it would do it. If I take it out it fixes it completely.

I put print tags to tell me how the loop happens, and it enters the `on_data` function (*Provided by tweepy to check if data has been received*), then it enters my `check_data` (*My function to check the data for phrases and tags I wish to filter out*) then it goes to my `retweet` and `like` function. After it does those it continues back up to the end of my `on_data`. If there is no retweet, it ends there. If there is one, then it does it all once more before ending.

**Streamer class:**

```
class LEDStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        # with open("tweets.json", "w") as write_file:
            # write_file.write(raw_data)
        print('at the top boi')

        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        usr = data['user']['screen_name']

        tweet_id = data['id']

        if len(data['entities']['hashtags']) != 0:
            tag = data['entities']['hashtags'][0]['text']

        else:
            tag = ''

        data_check(usr, tweet_id, tag, counter)

        print('here in on_data now')
```

**Data check function:**

```
def data_check(twitter_user, tweet, tag, count):
    print('Entering data_check')

    if tag == 'HUNTER_LED_OFF':
        requests.get('http://192.168.1.172/off')
        retweet_tweet(tweet)
        api.update_status('I turned the led off for you', tweet)
        print('off')
        return

    elif tag == 'HUNTER_LED_ON':
        requests.get('http://192.168.1.172/on')
        retweet_tweet(tweet)
        api.update_status('I turned the led on for you', tweet)
        print('on')
        return

    elif tag == 'led_test':
        retweet_tweet(tweet)
        api.update_status('Nice test bro *highfives* keep up the good work', tweet)
        print('tested')
        return

    elif twitter_user == 'realDonaldTrump':
        print('Make America Great Again!')
        return

    else:
        return
```

**Retweet function:**

```
def retweet_tweet(tweet_id):
    try:
        print('re-tweeting')
        api.retweet(tweet_id)
        api.create_favorite(tweet_id)
        print('done re-tweeting')
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e)
```

Console output of a received tweet with retweets enabled

```
at the top boi

Entering data_check
re-tweeting
done re-tweeting
off
here in on_data now
at the top boi
Entering data_check
re-tweeting
[{'code': 327, 'message': 'You have already retweeted this Tweet.'}]
off(this is me editing this just says the state of the command it did to my robot)
here in on_data now
```

Console log of with out the retweet line in the retweet function

```
at the top boi
Entering data_check
re-tweeting
done re-tweeting
off(this is me editing this just says the state of the command it did to my robot)
here in on_data now
```

Comment: In `Retweet function`, the code in not properly indented. Is it only in the question, or in the actual code as well?

Comment: @Zlytherin that is only in the question sorry must be a formatting error I missed when copying stuff over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so let's start this off by saying I'm mad at myself, and and currently not on speaking terms with my brain for this. Not sure I'll ever forgive the guy. Basically if you run into this error its because when you re tweet the tweet based on it hashtag, you make a post on your page with the hashtag on it. Tripping the bot to do things. To fix it I just set a variable
`text = data['text']` 
Then in my if statements I checked if the text part of my json file that is now stored in the variable I just made starts with 'RT'. By saying 
`if tag = '(your hashtag)' and not text.startswith('RT')`
I noticed while looking at the json files after I figured it out that they all do it.